# Zero diagonal commutator

Tags: matrices

Let $F = AB-BA$. Assume F has a zero-diagonal.

If I know F is hermitian, is there anything I can conclude about A and B?

If I know F is skew-hermitian, is there anything I can conclude about A and B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$F$ is Hermitian**

Consider the example
\begin{align}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\ \ \text{ and } \ \ 
B=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & i
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
where 
\begin{align}
[A, B] = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & i\\
-i & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Hence it's clear that $[A, B]$ is Hermitian with zero diagonal, but $B$ isn't Hermitian. Moreover, neither $A$ nor $B$ are invertible.

Here's a real example. Let
\begin{align}
C = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\ \ \text{ and } \ \ 
D=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
where 
\begin{align}
[C, D] = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -2\\
-2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Hence $[C, D]$ is Hermitian (since it's symmetric) with zero-diagonal, but neither $C$ nor $D$ are Hermitian.

**$F$ is Skew Hermitian**

Next, consider the example

\begin{align}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\ \ \text{ and } \ \ 
B=
\begin{pmatrix}
i & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
where 
\begin{align}
[A, B] = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & i\\
i & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Hence $[A, B]$ is skew Hermitian with zero diagonal, but $A$ isn't skew Hermitian. Like before, neither $A$ nor $B$ are invertible.

Finally, let us consider
\begin{align}
C = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\ \ \text{ and } \ \ 
D=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
where 
\begin{align}
[C, D] = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Hence $[C, D]$ is skew Hermitian (since it's skew symmetric) with zero-diagonal, but neither $C$ nor $D$ are skew Hermitian.

In conclusion, I don't know what you could actually conclude.